# ている pronunciation/internalization

Tags: pronunciation, subsidiary-verbs

How are things like ている/でいる split in terms of pronunciation? Do people internalize/think of it as te-iru or tei-ru when speaking? (there is a small difference in what it would sound like between those two) Or would it depend on the meaning? (Like 食べている vs 帰っている?)

Comment: are you asking of the pronunciation difference of っている and ている？

Comment: I think the point is that えい, despite the spelling, is pronounced like ええ. So the question is, is「食べている」pronounced identically to「食べてえる」(i.e. with a long え vowel), or is it pronounced more like「食べて・いる」(i.e without a long え vowel)?

Answer (score 6):

Grammatically, that いる is a [subsidiary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010) that follows the te-form of a verb.

So it's 食べて-いる, not 食べてい-る. If you are a beginner you can have a small pause between て and いる when reading.

Native speakers say this almost like a single word. Regarding how native speakers split sentences when reading very slowly, see the following questions (but please don't go overthink it).

- [Spaces in children's books](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27624/5010)
- https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43079/5010

Answer (score 3):

Basically, "ている" and "でいる" are always pronounced as *te-iru* and *de-iru* respectively.
However you can hear "食べている" as *tabeteiru* and "帰っている？" as *kaetteiru?* without any split.

Actually we often say not "帰っている？" but "帰ってる？kaetteru?"

These variations of pronunciation don't make difference in their meaning.